# VerifyError: Incompatible argument to function

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a Gradle 4.4.1 script which occasionally fails. This happens on multiple machines, usually before running the `test` task.

Here's the relevant log (acquired while running `gradlew test --info`):

```
Up-to-date check for task ':test' took 4.191 secs. It is not up-to-date because:
  No history is available.
(class: org/gradle/process/internal/worker/child/WorkerProcessClassPathProvider$CacheInitializer, method: remapClass signature: (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/zip/ZipOutputStream;)V) Incompatible argument to function
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/gradle/process/internal/worker/child/WorkerProcessClassPathProvider$CacheInitializer, method: remapClass signature: (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/zip/ZipOutputStream;)V) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerProcessClassPathProvider.findClassPath(WorkerProcessClassPathProvider.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:34)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ApplicationClassesInSystemClassLoaderWorkerImplementationFactory.prepareJavaCommand(ApplicationClassesInSystemClassLoaderWorkerImplementationFactory.java:89)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.build(DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.forkProcess(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.run(BuildOperationIdentifierPreservingRunnable.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Version information:

```
./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-20 15:45:23 UTC
Revision:     10ed9dc355dc39f6307cc98fbd8cea314bdd381c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Linux 4.13.5-coreos-r2 amd64
```

This example happened on a freshly set up machine, i.e. Gradle downloaded all required stuff just before. If haven't found anything about this bug on the internet, so any hints on how to fix it are appreciated.

Upgrading to Gradle 4.5 also didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be Eclipselink weaving, which I had enabled [according to an answer here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23825455/49548). I had this in my `build.gradle`:

```
compileTestJava.doLast {
    ClassLoader antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
    sourceSets.main.compileClasspath.each{File f -> antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())}

    ant.taskdef(name: "weave",
        classname: "org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeaveAntTask",
        classpath: configurations.compile.asPath
    )

    ant.weave(source: compileJava.destinationDir,
        target: compileJava.destinationDir,
        persistenceinfo: processResources.destinationDir 
    )
}
```

After removing this part the problem is gone.